# Can i just simply sealed a bottle of plant and expect it will grow well?

Tags: tropical

i bought 2 little pitcher plants from Bangkok which is sealed in a bottle for the past 7 months until now i feel it needed a bigger place to continue growing.
Now my question is should i sealed the bigger bottle once im done transferring?
thanks y'all

Comment: It always helps to add pictures as you'll get more interest though I guess one could answer this without.